# bootstrap5 navbar justify content between doesnt work

Tags: flexbox, navbar, bootstrap-5

Hi im trying to make a navbar with 3 link in container class.I tried justify content between on navbar but it doesnt work justify content center works but between class doesnt work on navbar links displays like block.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex ">
    <div class="container justify-content-between ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between w-100">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

You can try this.

Comment: Thank you sidman it worked out . but i dont understand why only justify content center didnt worked @sidman2048 
`navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-between w-100`  only this code is worked out also why did you use flex-row and align-items-center

Comment: By default flex-direction set the row value. For safer side I used flex-row class. And it is good practice that we use align-items-center to align items center vertically.

Comment: This was the correct solution as of current (Bootstrap v5).

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are using flex on different element and `justify-content` in different element,
my suggestion is to use this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

also as a bonus suggestion use `header` instead of `nav` and replace the first `div` with `nav` for SEO purpose by using right semantic elements

Comment: sadly it didnt work i still get same result and thanks i changed as header and nav

Comment: check in inspector whether the class `justify-content-between` is applying the property of `justify-content:space-between` if not then bootstrap must not be applied in your app